# running django python 3.4 on mod_wsgi with apache2

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

Hi I am getting the error below when going to the website url on ubuntu server 14.10 running apache 2 with mod_wsgi and python on django.

My django application uses python 3.4 but it seems to be defaulting to python 2.7, I am unable to import image from PIL and AES from pycrypto.

> ImportError at / 
>  cannot import name _imaging
>  Request
>   Method:   GET
>  Request URL:   
>  Django Version:   1.7.3
>   Exception Type:   ImportError
>  Exception Value:   
>  cannot import
>   name _imaging
>  Exception
>   Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in
>   , line 63
>  Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
>  Python
>   Version:  2.7.6
>  Python Path: 
>  ['/var/www/blabla',
>  
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
>  
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>  
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>  
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>  
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>  
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>  
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>   '/var/www/blabla',
>  
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages']

Comment: Yep. No doubt about it using Python 2.7. How have you configured the Apache site to use mod_wsgi? Can you post your site configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that mod_wsgi is compiled against a specific version of python, so you need a py3.4 version of mod_wsgi. You may be able to get one from your os's package repository or you can build one without too much drama. From memory you'll need gcc and python-dev packages (python3-dev?) to build.

OK, quick google, for ubuntu 14.10: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` should install a py3 version of mod_wsgi (will probably want to remove the existing py2 version).

Adding a shebang line won't do any good as the python interpreter is already loaded before the wsgi.py script is read.

Comment: Lifesaver answer. I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here your application is using *py2* interpreter with *py3* compiled modules, which is no-go.

One simple possible solution that comes me in mind is to add or change first line of *manage.py* to `#!/usr/bin/python3`. This will tell script to be interpreted with *py3*.

Next on guess list would be misconfiguration in *.wsgi file or apache config, whichever you are using.

Comment: Apache Config:  DocumentRoot /var/www/html    
 
 WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/project folder/MITLogger:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages     
 WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp  
 WSGIScriptAlias / /project folder/MITLogger/MITLogger/wsgi.py  
 
 <Directory /project folder/MITLogger/MITLogger>  
 <Files wsgi.py>  
 Require all granted  
 </Files>  
 </Directory>

Comment: wsgi.py: import os, sys  
# add the hellodjango project path into the sys.path
sys.path.append('/project folder/MITLogger')

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MITLogger.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I actually fixed the issue myself this morning by running the make install of mod_wsgi with .configure pointing to python3.4.

I think you were right Adam.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure just changing WSGIPythonHome doesn't work. It is  useful to select a virtualenv though. Mark my answer as correct if you deem it so :-)

Comment: To clear something up - there was another answer here suggesting to just change `WSGIPythonHome`. `WSGIPythonHome` will choose the interpreter but will only work when mod_wsgi is compiled against the same major/minor version of python that you are pointing to.