# Django: Templatetags doesn't work with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I wanted to deploy my app on production server, once I completed and tested one module. Till now, app was working on embedded server with Django 1.9.2 framework (with Python 3.5). I deployed Django via mod_wsgi through Apache on Centos 7.
I did some tests after deployment. Seems that Templatetags are not working properly, as always "0" is returned (or not calculated at all?) to template, while mod_wsgi is in use. Same applies even if I put any constant to templatetag (below) and try return it to template, just to test how it works. 
I did exactly same checks with same machine (Linux), but I used embedded server. In case of embedded server all information are passed and counted properly. 
I thought that this is permissions related issue. I check this carefully and seems that all file access rights are set properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName nid.example.com
        <Directory /home/nid/nid/nid>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess nid python-path=/home/nid/nid:/home/nid/nid-venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup nid
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nid/nid/nid/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

templatetag:

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()
@register.assignment_tag()
def count_expire_days(end_date, renew_date):
    last_valid_day = end_date
    first_renew_day = renew_date
    today = datetime.date.today()
    diff_last_day = last_valid_day - today
    diff_whole_period = last_valid_day - first_renew_day
    period = diff_whole_period.days
    expire_days = diff_last_day.days
    percentage = (expire_days/period)*100
    return int(percentage)
```

I was playing with file permissions, but without luck. 
What can be wrong? How to debug Django templatetags, to understand why this is not working?

Comment: What do you mean, template tags don't work? What happens when you use them? What error do you see? Also, please show your template and view.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to put all required information. Please check description above. In general application is working properly as i wanted to work, but this is problem with Django deployment with mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite hidden.
I use Centos 7. At default it runs Python 2.7. Even if we install Python 3.4 (the newest available Centos package, right now) and all surrounding packages, there is more work to be done. I spotted that Django is showing that it still uses Python 2.7, while whole virtualenv was pure Python 3.4.

Root cause: outdated **mod_wsgi** Apache module. Its original version was **3.4**, while the newest available (with Python 3 support) is **4.4.22**. To solve this issue you need to compile mod_wsgi from sources and load it into Apache.
After changes, application is working as expected. All values are counted correctly. Reason why this was not working is a difference how python 2.7 and 3.4 process the data.

Inspiration: [running django python 3.4 on mod_wsgi with apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019310/running-django-python-3-4-on-mod-wsgi-with-apache2)